# Companion's Leaders are hostile, but not attacking

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Villas and Farkas are always chasing after me with their weapons raised, but they won't attack me (I'm the companions harbinger). I just did the Liberation of Skyrim quest so I'm wondering if I accidentally killed someone with my shout? How can I fix this? I can't fast travel any more because they won't stop chasing me.

Comment: You probably have a bounty somewhere. Villas and Farkas are part of the guard faction for some reason, and so will chase you if your bounty is high enough.

Comment: I have tried to talk to guards around whiterun to pay off a bounty but they don't say anything. I do have a rather high bounty in Riften, though. Could that affect the companions? I am still in good with the thieves guild.